# Change shortcuts in Windows to Linux layout

Tags: linux, windows, visual-studio-code, shortcut

I use Visual Studio Code at work under Ubuntu and at home under Windows. Strangely enough, the shortcuts are different for basically every command. I'm looking for a way to change the layout under Windows to match that of Linux without inputting every single shortcut by hand. Is there a way?

Comment: Find another editor that already has the Linux comparable shortcuts (e.g. have a look at [Geany](http://www.geany.org/), source at [Geany on github](https://github.com/geany/geany/)]. (also functions as IDE) I know it is getting better, but you still must take care regarding Linux file permissions when editing from the Windows side through `%APPDATA%/lxss`. Other editors may be closer. Other options are [CodeBlocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/), and even [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/). All implementations are on the order of ten megabytes or so, not like the 4+Gig for VS.

Comment: Use `Preferences | Keyboard Shortcuts` to first check which are the shortcuts on each platform. Then you might get some idea what's up.